# Passing id between 2 lightning components

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, dynamiccomponent

I have two separate components, I want to pass the **survey id** after saving to create the **questions with the same survey id**.

here is the screenshot of survey form : 
[image]

**and my code for survey component**

```
        <lightning:layoutItem >

            <lightning:icon iconName="standard:scan_card" alternativeText="My Survey"/>

        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">

            <div class="page-section page-header">

                <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">Survey ITELIOS</h1>

                <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">by itelios</h2>

            </div>

        </lightning:layoutItem>

    </lightning:layout>

<!-- / PAGE HEADER -->

<!--PAGE BODY-->

<lightning:layout >

    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">

         <form class="slds-form--stacked">   

            <lightning:input aura:id="SurveyName" label="Survey name"

                             name="surveyname"

                             value="{!v.survey.Name}"

                             required="true"/>

            <lightning:button label="Create Survey"

                              class="slds-m-top--medium"

                              variant="brand"

                              onclick="{!c.clickCreate}"/>

        </form>

    </lightning:layoutItem>

</lightning:layout>

<!--/PAGE BODY-->
```

**Second Component**

```
<aura:handler name="DeleteRowEvt" event="c:SurveyItelios_DeleteRowEvt" action="{!c.removeDeletedRow}"/>
<aura:handler name="AddRowEvt" event="c:SurveyItelios_AddNewRowEvt" action="{!c.addNewRow}"/>

<aura:attribute name="ReponseList" type="surveyitelios_question_options__c[]"/> 
<div class="slds-page-header">
<h1 class="slds-page-header__title">  Questions</h1>
</div>
<aura:attribute name="QuestionLi" type="surveyitelios_questions__c"
                     default="{'sobjectType':'surveyitelios_questions__c',
                      'Name': '',
                   }"
                  />       
  <lightning:layout >
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
         <form class="slds-form--stacked">   
            <lightning:input aura:id="Name" label="Question name"

                             name="Name"

                             value="{!v.QuestionLi.Name}"

                             required="true"/>

              <lightning:input aura:id="input_type_id__c" label="id du type"

                             name="input_type_id__c"

                             value="{!v.QuestionLi.input_type_id__c}"

                             required="true"/>
             <lightning:input aura:id="surveyitelios_survey__c" label="id du sondage"

                             name="surveyitelios_survey__c"

                             value="{!v.QuestionLi.surveyitelios_survey__c}"
                              required="true"/>
         </form>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Les réponses
    
 
     
        
            
                
                    S.No

```
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="name">Choix</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Valeur">Valeur</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>    
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ReponseList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
            <c:SurveyItelios_dynamicRowItem ReponseInstance="{!item}" rowIndex="{!index}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>

<!--Save Button which is call Save js function on click --> 
<ui:button class="btn btn-default" press="{!c.Save}" >Save</ui:button>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What is your specific question?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't know how I can pass id from the button above to another component.

Comment: I think you are looking for [events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_intro.htm) to be able to communicate between components.

Comment: Can you post the second components' code?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lightning event to communicate the survey Id to the parent component, then the parent can pass it along to the other component either using an `aura:attribute` and binding the new value into the child component's survey Id attribute (recommended for your case), or by calling an `aura:method` defined on the child component and passing the survey Id as a parameter into that method.

See how to pass information from a child to a parent via a component event here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm

As a general rule of thumb, component events are used to pass information to the parent, and the parent can use methods to pass/call the child component to do something.

Bonus Edit:

A really great article from [Philippe Ozil](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/author/pozil) about best practices for communicating between components: [Salesforce Developers Blog: Lightning Inter-Component Communication Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-inter-component-communication-patterns.html)